# Trying to find a story of a man who strapped a magnet to his forehead, has visions

Tags: identification-request

Many years ago I read a story of a man who experimented with a magnet strapped to his forehead. From what I remember, he examined this experiment in his attic study. He harnessed a magnet on his forehead for what I believe was an hour per day.

After a time, he noticed a ghostly boy running through his study. Then, his world was immersed within another, noticing a young man and a woman sitting next to a tree. A final vision of the same man and women, but this time they actually notice him also and seem frightened.

I can't recall if this was a fiction or some actual claim of an experiment. I've been trying all over the web to find it with no luck.

Edit: Adding as many details as I can. I'm having trouble remembering everything about it but I'll try my best.

The age of the story: Really foggy on this but I want to say between the 1850s and the early 1900s.

Medium, read online, was definitely a shorter story. If printed would be maybe just a few pages.

Time when the story was read: I read this story online about 15 years ago. I can't remember the website or the format of the site.

Language of the story: English (possibly from the US). I believe the subject in the story was some kind of a self-proclaimed modern philosopher.

Location: I am from the US but given that I read it online and I'm foggy with the details, the origin could have been from elsewhere.

The appearance of the book: There where no photos or scans of an actual book.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! Can you remember any more identifying details: for example, when is "many years ago"? where did you read this story (in a magazine, anthology, collection, online)? was it a novel or short story? was it written in English or possibly translated? where was it set? We've got a [checklist](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/779/17) which might help to jog your memory for more details. Every little helps!

Comment: @Randal'Thor thanks for the follow up. I edited the original question to fit in as many of the checklist items as possible. I'm sorry, it was so long ago I'm really having a hard time remember everything.

Comment: FWIW, you can find "nonfiction" books about this practice. It's supposed to stimulate the pineal gland.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for "[The Science of Oneness](https://web.archive.org/web/20051023052852/http://ascension2000.com/ConvergenceIII/)" as per [the discussion here](https://www.godlikeproductions.com/forum1/message83119/pg1?c1=1&c2=1&disclaimer=Continue):

> Walter Rawls, who worked with the effects of monopolar magnetic fields on matter with the late Albert Roy Davis, told me in a telephone conversation of his experiments with a North pole magnet situated over the pineal gland.
>
> A mask was made which held the North pole end of a long cylindrical magnet over the pineal gland. The purpose was to stimulate the gland and see if there was anything to this ‘third eye’ business. Exposure was in the range of 10-30 minutes per day over a period of about 4 weeks.
>
> Within the first week, he was sitting at his desk reading documents when he noticed something move out of the corner of his eye. As he looked up, the ghostly figure of a man had walked through one wall, moved across the room and disappeared through another wall. The figure was totally unaware of Walter. Further exposures to this North pole field took place over a second and third week.
>
> The second week, the same ghostly figure moved through the room and glanced toward Walter as he passed through. This time, the figure appeared to have slightly more detail, not quite so ghostly.
>
> The third week, while busy working on documents, Walter noticed a change in the room. When he looked up, the wall had dissolved away and he was looking at a small hill where a man and woman sat beneath a tree. It was the same ghostly male figure who he had seen on the other occasions. He sat quit still, watching this pastoral scene for several minutes.
>
> The man looked over toward Walter and appeared startled. It was as if he clearly SAW Walter this time and possibly recognized Walter as the ghost that he had seen the previous week! The image faded away and the wall restored to its normal condition. From that moment on, Walter never used the pineal stimulator again.

Found with a search for `science fiction "magnet * forehead" pineal gland`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for helping me find this. It's exactly what I was looking for and now I have some answers on something I read on the fly 15ish yrs ago.